# Can you do an isometric perspective with HTML5 <canvas>?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, perspective

It is possible to do an isometric perspective with HTML5 `<canvas>`? It is with `setTransform`? Or does it exist another way?

Example:

```
ctxt.setTransform (1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Something like the perspective of Farmville.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can draw whatever you want on the canvas down to the individual pixel, so any question like "is it possible" will have a "yes" answer.

<strike>If you mean if a 3d pipeline is already built-in in the canvas the answer is no, canvas context is 2d so commands are 2d.</strike> Canvas elements do actually support a full 3d pipeline (webgl) but that is very low level and geared toward giving access to a GPU (more specifically is designed to represent how current hardware works); the "high-level" abstract API is instead 2d. You can set up a 2d matrix that will make your square-drawing commands looking like an isometric view, but you won't be able to draw anything above or below that plane as high-level commands only handle 2d coordinates.

You can of course do 3d rendering (either isometric or perspective) in a canvas 2d context using standard 3d->2d mappings techniques. See for example [this 4k demo](http://raksy.dyndns.org/torus.html) that is using only canvas 2d context and javascript ([here is a youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHT23NnW-EY) of the same if your browser doesn't support HTML5).

For an isometric view the matrix setting part is simpler... for example

```
var cs = Math.cos(angle1), sn = Math.sin(angle1);
var h = Math.cos(angle2);
var a = 100*cs, b = -100*sn, c = 200;
var d = h*100*sn, e = h*100*cs, f = 200;
ctx.setTransform(a, d, b, e, c, f);
```

where `ctx` is a canvas context will set up a matrix that:

- has an XY rotation angle of `angle1`
- has a view tilt angle of `angle2`
- maps a length of 1 to 100 pixels
- maps (0, 0) to 200, 200

You can see a small example of these formulas in action [on this example page](http://raksy.dyndns.org/iso.html).

Comment: my question is more simple. I want to transform a normal plain, like a square to another perspective. The game is just an example. An example of what i want: http://graffiti.virgin.net/ljmayes.mal/plotting/Iso.gif >>>thanks

Comment: @Fel: I've extended the answer to show explicit formulas for isometric view 2d->2d mapping and a link to an animated example of those formulas.

Answer (score 3):

Well to make an isometric game its not so much as skewing the whole canvas, its more about the graphics you use. For example the tiles are generally h=w/2. So in a normal game you'd have a tile thats 32x32 in an isometric game you'd make it 32x16. Also the placement of tiles is a bit different to compensate for the angle.

Short answer yes isometric games are fully possible using canvas. Look at [Freeciv](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) for an example of one.

Another good place to ask on the specifics of isometric game creation would be https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks Loktar. I want to create an image distortion, simple thing, like this http://graffiti.virgin.net/ljmayes.mal/plotting/Iso.gif

Comment: @NiCkNewman http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeciv#Freeciv-web maybe its changed in the 4 years since this answer, but according to wikipedia they still are for the web version, and were most definitely when I wrote this answer. It was a big deal in 2010.